# NSMutableArray:How to allow duplicate values

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm reading a JSON code such as:

```
[{"question_id":"1",
  "trigger_value":"Yes",
  "question_text":"What is your first    name?",
  "question_type":"YN"},    
 {"question_id":"2",
  "trigger_value":"Yes",
  "question_text":"What is your second name?",
  "question_type":"YN"}
]
```

But once it's set into NSMutableArray, the duplicate values are deleted. I would like to allow them to check the question_type for each question.

```
  NSString *question_id;
  NSString *question_text;
  NSString *question_type;

   while (dicjson = (NSDictionary*)[enumerator nextObject]) {
      question_id = [dicjson objectForKey:@"question_id"];        
     question_type = [dicjson objectForKey:@"question_type"];

     [mutjson setObject:question_id    forKey:question_type];
}
```

Would you give me any idea of allowing duplicate values...?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mutjson looks like a mutable dictionary and not a mutable Array.

So yes, in a dictionary object if you are setting the same key, it will overwrite the previous value.
If you need to store dictionary object, create a mutable array and add each object inside that array as a dintionary object...

```
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

while (dicjson = (NSDictionary*)[enumerator nextObject]) {
     question_id = [dicjson objectForKey:@"question_id"];        
     question_type = [dicjson objectForKey:@"question_type"];
     [result addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:question_id forKey:question_type]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a mutable dictionary. I've tried your code and it works like a charm. I have another thing i want to ask, is there any way to store question_id, question_text and question_type in an array? Otherwise i would make 2 arrays.

Comment: Well my code stores it in a single array, so why do you want to use 2 arrays? If you want to search the array later, and this is your problem, you should use the NSPredicate class. Search stackoverflow for NSPredicate to see how it's done (it's quite easy)

Comment: I would like to display the questions in a form and input as well. so i would like to see if that's yes/no question or textfield type question. Thanks for your suggestion, i will have a reaseach on NSPredicate.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `setObject:forKey:` in NSMutableArray. You have to use `addObject:`. Its also much easier to create the array like this:

```
NSArray *values = [jsonDict allValues];
```

Comment: Thanks, you gave me some idea.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing an array for a dictionary. An array can hold duplicate values. A dictionary cannot hold duplicate keys.

The JSON response is an array of dictionaries. The way you've written your code, specifically `[mutjson setObject:question_id forKey:question_type];` seems to suggest that you are simply using a dictionary.

If you would like to check the question type for each question, try instead:

```
NSString *question_type;

for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in dicjson) {
    // I would suggest renaming dicjson to something more descriptive, like results
    question_type = [dict objectForKey: @"question_type"];

    // Do what you would like now that you know the type
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your explanation was clear now i can see how i was confused. I will use more descriptive names, too.